# fos user: allow route to many roles even if user have just one role

Tags: symfony, security, authorization, fosuserbundle, roles

In my symfony project, using the FOS bundle, I have 4 roles like this:

- ROLE_USER_ONE
- ROLE_USER_TWO
- ROLE_USER_THREE

They can't access to the same views, except for one. This is my controller for render the view:

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER_ONE', 'ROLE_USER_TWO', 'ROLE_USER_THREE')")
 * @Route("/add-note", name="add_user_note")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function addNoteToUserAction()
{
  $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');

  if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER_ONE', 'ROLE_USER_TWO', 'ROLE_USER_THREE')) {
    /* ... some persist datas and process here ... */
    return $this->render('MyBundle:NoteUser:addNote.html.twig', array(
    ));
  } else {
      throw new \Exception('You have no right to access this page');
  }
}
```

To test the view rendering, I create a user with role ROLE_USER_TWO. And when I render the view I have this error:

> Expression "has_role('ROLE_USER_ONE', 'ROLE_USER_TWO',
> 'ROLE_USER_THREE')" denied access.

As I understand, Symfony expected the user have all the roles, how can I allow the view access to user which as at less one of these roles in my controller annotations and controller code?

Comment: I believe, what you are doing now ist to force the user to have ALL of these roles..
Try something like (has_role('ROLE_USER_ONE') or has_role('ROLE_USER_TWO') or has_role('ROLE_USER_THREE'))

Comment: if($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER_ONE') ||$securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER_TWO') || $securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USER_THREE') i guess. But perhaps there is a best way

Comment: Also, if you use the @Security Annotation, you don't have to repeat the same in the function

Comment: @EmanuelOster I know that I repeat the action in the same fucntion in that way, I do like that in order to have the answer of my question for the two ways. 

By the way, your first comment is the good one using annotations, I have tried it just right now and it works, that's what I was looking for. Make an answer in order I validate your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @Letsrocks your comment is a good answer too, but like you said maybe it's not the best way, just notice that you give me a good possibility to implement the `security.authorization_checker` to check on many roles.

Thank you by the way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of trying to put every role into the same `has_role()` statement, you have to concatenate them with `or` like this:

```
@Security("has_role('ROLE_USER_ONE') or has_role('ROLE_USER_TWO') or has_role('ROLE_USER_THREE')")
```

This way, you are actually checking that the current user has at least one of these roles instead of all of them.

Comment: Perfect answer.!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you're looking for [role hierarchy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles). Your configuration will be like:

```
security:
    # ...

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_USER_ONE : ROLE_USER_BASE
        ROLE_USER_TWO : ROLE_USER_BASE
        ROLE_USER_THREE : ROLE_USER_BASE
```

So users with `ROLE_USER_ONE` role has also role `ROLE_USER_BASE` etc. Then, in your controller you just need to check only for `ROLE_USER_BASE`:

```
/**
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER_BASE')")
 * @Route("/add-note", name="add_user_note")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function addNoteToUserAction()
```